# Call initializer from a Super Super Class in Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a subclass of `UITableViewController`:

```
class ClassA : UITableViewController {

    // MARK: Init
    convenience init() {
        self.init(style: .Grouped)
    }

    convenience init(form: FormDescriptor) {
        self.init()
        self.form = form
    }

    override init(style: UITableViewStyle) {
        super.init(style: style)
    }

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String!, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle!) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
        baseInit()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        baseInit()
    }    
}
```

I made a subclass of `ClassA`:

```
class ClassB : ClassA {

  override init(style: UITableViewStyle) {
    super.init(style: style)
  }

  convenience init() {
    self.init(style: .Grouped)
    self.form = getForm()
  }

  required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }
}
```

I tried to init `ClassB` with the initializer from `UITableViewController` which uses the `UITableViewStyle`. When running the code I get:

> fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer `init(nibName:bundle:)`

How can I init `ClassB` with the `style` property from `UITableViewController`?

Comment: Implement the init(nibName:bundle:) in ClassB also. Parent class initialiser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put that code in your `ClassB`:

```
override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String!, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle!) {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
}
```

Then you will be able to init `ClassB` as follows:

```
let b = ClassB(style: UITableViewStyle.Grouped)
```